# What does the notation $P\{(T,T,T)\}=1/8$ mean?

Tags: probability, random-variables

A function is denoted by a function name followed by round braces and the argument variable and closing round brace. Example: $f(x)$.

A variable denoted by set is written as $X = \{a,b,c\}.$

What does $P\{(T, T, T)\}$ mean ?

**EDIT2:** The above notation is from the book "A first course in probability" by Sheldon Ross Chapter 4 Random Variables page 117, Example 1a

> Suppose that our experiment consists of tossing 3 fair coins. If we
>   letYdenote thenumber of heads that appear, thenYis a random variable
>   taking on one of the values0, 1, 2, and 3 with respective
>   probabilities
>
> $P\{Y=0\}=P\{(T,T,T)\}=\frac{1}{8}$

Comment: You should really clarify in which context this notation popped up, with examples where it is used being particularly helpful

Comment: Added the example from where it is copied from .

Comment: My interpretation of this is $P\{X\}$ means "the probability of the event $X$". In this case, the probability of getting three consecutive tails (T) on your coins. That might also explain the $18$ you keep seeing, which I suspect is meant to be $1/8$ (which is $(1/2)^3$, the probability of the event in question).

Comment: Fixed typo 18 as 1/8. Your interpretation is most likey right, since this text book is a standard, i am assuming this notation is the accepted in this field and i am looking for the source.

Comment: To @Talespin_Kit: I edited your Q for better formatting, please check...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Thanks very much

Comment: As an aside, I find it far more common to see $P$ as an operator or function that takes an event written as a subset of the sample space or an event written as a boolean condition and outputs the corresponding probability.  I see it more commonly written as $P(Y=0)$ and as $P(\{(T,T,T)\})$

Comment: The end result is that different authors will use different notations... but the *intention* of the notation used in these contexts should make it clear what is intended.  In the above, however it so happens that the author notated it, seeing $P$ and $T,T,T$ enclosed, whether as $P(T,T,T)$ or $Pr(\{(T,T,T)\})$ or $P(1_T\cap 2_T\cap 3_T)$ or however else, this should get across the meaning of "*The probability that in three consecutive flips of a coin all three coins turned up tails.*"  Similarly, $Pr(Y=0)$ in the above should imply "*The probability that the number of heads is zero*"